# Plot transparent 3D boxes using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, visualization

I have a data file "data.txt" which contains the coordinates of the borders of several boxes in three dimensions. Each line represents a single box. The file contains over 100 boxes.

```
        x_Min x_Max y_Min y_Max z_Min z_Max
        -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2
        0.2 0.4 -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2
        ....
        ...
        ..
```

Now I want to plot that. In two dimensions it is very easy by using

```
plot "boxes.txt" u 1:2:3:4 w boxxyerrorbars
```

With `(x-Value):(y-Value):(Half Width):(Half Height)`.

Than I get this:
[image]

But how can I achieve this in three dimensions? I didn't find any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still interested in a gnuplot solution...

If it is sufficient to just draw the edges of the boxes you can use the plotting style `with vectors`. You simply need to select the necessary columns and plot all edges in 3 loops. Here gnuplot's integer division (e.g. `1/2=0`) is helpful.

However, if you want to plot surfaces and hide surfaces if they are covered by another box you'd better use `with pm3d` (check `help pm3d`). Then, however, you have to re-shape your input data.

**Script:**

```
### plot edges of boxes in 3D
reset session

$Data <<EOD
x_Min  x_Max  y_Min  y_Max  z_Min  z_Max
 -0.2   0.2   -0.2    0.2   -0.2    0.2
  0.3   0.4   -0.1    0.2   -0.1    0.2
 -1.5  -0.5   -1.2   -0.4   -0.9    0.0
  0.5   1.0   -1.0   -0.5   -0.5   -0.1
  0.0   0.3   -1.4   -1.1   -1.0   -0.7
EOD

set xyplane relative 0
set view equal xyz
set view 60,30,1.7
set xtics 0.5
set ytics 0.5
set ztics 0.5
set key noautotitle

splot for [i=0:3] $Data u 1:i/2+3:i%2+5:($2-$1):(0):(0):0 w vec lc var nohead, \
      for [i=0:3]    '' u i/2+1:3:i%2+5:(0):($4-$3):(0):0 w vec lc var nohead, \
      for [i=0:3]    '' u i/2+1:i%2+3:5:(0):(0):($6-$5):0 w vec lc var nohead
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Nice solution :) Would be helpful if you could add the gnuplot version you used.

Comment: @Gilfoyle this was created with gnuplot 5.2.8 but it works for gnuplot>=5.0.0. If you have gnuplot 4.x you need some adaptions (i.e. read data from file, because no datablocks at that time).

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution using Python and Matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


DIM = 3;

# Unit cube
cube = [[[0.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0]],\
        [[0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0]],\
        [[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0]],\
        [[1.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0]],\
        [[1.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0]],\
        [[1.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0]],\
        [[1.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0]],\
        [[0.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0]],\
        [[0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0]],\
        [[0.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0],[1.0,1.0]],\
        [[1.0,1.0],[0.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0]],\
        [[0.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0]]]

# Number of Cubes
numb_Cubes = 5

# Array with positions [x, y, z]
pos = [[0 for x in range(DIM)] for y in range(numb_Cubes)]   
for k  in range(numb_Cubes):
    for d in range(DIM):
        pos[k][d] = random.uniform(-1,1)

# Size of cubes
size_of_cubes = [0 for y in range(numb_Cubes)]  
for k in range(numb_Cubes):
    size_of_cubes[k] = random.random()

# Limits
xmin, xmax = -1, 1
ymin, ymax = -1, 1
zmin, zmax = -1, 1

for n in range(numb_Cubes):
    for k in range(len(cube)):
            x = np.linspace(cube[k][0][0]*size_of_cubes[n]+pos[n][0], cube[k][0][1]*size_of_cubes[n]+pos[n][0], 2)
            y = np.linspace(cube[k][1][0]*size_of_cubes[n]+pos[n][1], cube[k][1][1]*size_of_cubes[n]+pos[n][1], 2)
            z = np.linspace(cube[k][2][0]*size_of_cubes[n]+pos[n][2], cube[k][2][1]*size_of_cubes[n]+pos[n][2], 2)

            ax.plot(x, y, z, 'black', lw=1)
            ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
            ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
            ax.set_zlim([zmin,ymax])
```

The result I get:

[image]

I am still interested in a solution for gnuplot or a faster solution for Python.